# Where to find more infos about Xwayland command line options?

Tags: xorg, documentation, wayland, sandbox

My gnome-session starts a `Xwayland` instance which I can find

```
$> pgrep -a Xwayland
995 /usr/bin/Xwayland :0 -rootless -terminate -accessx -core -listen 4 -listen 5 -displayfd 6
```

which shows that there are quite some command line options supplied.

There is some help available via

```
$> Xwayland -help 2>&1 | grep -e 'rootless\|terminate\|accessx\|core\|listen\|displayfd'
-core                  generate core dump on fatal error
-displayfd fd          file descriptor to write display number to when ready to connect
-nolisten string       don't listen on protocol
-listen string         listen on protocol
-pn                    accept failure to listen on all ports
-nopn                  reject failure to listen on all ports
-terminate             terminate at server reset
[+-]accessx [ timeout [ timeout_mask [ feedback [ options_mask] ] ] ]
                       enable/disable accessx key sequences
-rootless              run rootless, requires wm support
-listen fd             add give fd as a listen socket
```

however there is not more insightfull `man Xwayland`.

Where can I find more information about the options the usage of Xwayland. Similar to what is discussed on [this github issue](https://github.com/swaywm/wlroots/issues/1442), my goal/intention is to be able to start another instance of Xwayland with the purpose to separate/sandbox the GUI part of applications (which by themselves are already somewhat sandbox using different `uid` `gui` and linux `namespaces`)

Comment: This is the specific case where the tool does not have good manpages, and the `-help` switch just assume that the user knows some concepts that are related to Xorg, Wayland and Window Managers in a bigger picture...

Comment: Note that `accessx` and `core` *are* in the `-help` output, but there's a typo in your grep regex (`accessx|\core` should be `accessx\|core`)

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for making me aware of the typo

Comment: @nwildner I was looking at https://github.com/GNOME/mutter/blob/2d80fd02e76bbe17dc52072299dda92ab88c99c0/src/wayland/meta-xwayland.c which shows the code used to startup `Xwayland` in gnome, as to augment my picture a bit. However for something as having a second instance of Xwayland I would yet like to avoid a need to read through massive amounts of code, any help? At the level of command line options at least it seems that stuff should be usable without requiring deep deep knowledge of the internats, right?